# Use Python Re module to extract text from multiline

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to retrieve the `Auth=` value from the multiline string below. I've tried Python `re.match` with no success. Will appreciate if I can get any help?

> SID=DQAAALsAAABCeyCMlOaYMHkv55TUQFxA71fxE1LpgpmL1G_o8YennFwBhar2I_LNmJjGjvLHVQy8tSRfYdLnUIHhKyD0FTZBzXyG_s8U4Pt97n9hPz68ZFSM42Qv6Qxuk74TQygHJXhjLWXNuD5mMsh8_MAs-nmhSToNFIyWoP-uTZ_LN2yQS1o9MB43fzuIIxp-1euXGxMceVVrjyidrYeEB13HS5kMHH-HGjiZhoIJBmu5es7pLPj9Ie8NJZ1K3kFhdVEJa4sLSID=DQAAAL4AAACypRIVyVXcs5zYIeUEt9v-wEwPKgQ8Oe23_URsDeHCg-rR2qQK4dTxPV1J6BPTO-6Zly2H9t4sVhm0vHe8IT6sKLdX2IQ8PgGMtSHQNkpQ8zEan0CyFyUetbSW4af6mlk2pksDpvXNm5GtNTj5eTwkCQUmgGep42u5iuCGFy-o9a1cQWz45NO_J8zIYnBdOqlheNTqaMWpi4hpr-_u8Muzs4RjlEbkuYfDu7MrdsJAFwxf0BVW2cGBtB-K2jwaK7wAuth=873hdyjsbcvuei73hckwoxnaodbc8dnskc8HU1mKRqxh6yEU-9tqx148GqC7h90_190ZzxpEZOHAH5HTptliylRXvMPyqPyijMNu21bOA6ZhvZFuL8YNB3KF63YuV0n5TFJd1-rMI2LQIdPMVBnsxnEGrLIeFOugAFCZ_3OelAc4XjeKdDvIowxkNnvaooXT4kxtkQWzieA3JRKy3Y-Lbi7E0qiXC99GtHVDh5VWvdTs2LCv3wnRULtLp6ZCoToZ8qoUWMzU9PZldsKSnE

Comment: show us your code that is not working

Comment: try `re.search`. `match` only matches at the start of a string. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

text = "SID=DQAAALsAAABCeyCMlOaYMHkv55TUQFxA71fxE1LpgpmL1G_o8YennFwBhar2I_LNmJjGjvLHVQy8tSRfYdLnUIHhKyD0FTZBzXyG_s8U4Pt97n9hPz68ZFSM42Qv6Qxuk74TQygHJXhjLWXNuD5mMsh8_MAs-nmhSToNFIyWoP-uTZ_LN2yQS1o9MB43fzuIIxp-1euXGxMceVVrjyidrYeEB13HS5kMHH-HGjiZhoIJBmu5es7pLPj9Ie8NJZ1K3kFhdVEJa4sLSID=DQAAAL4AAACypRIVyVXcs5zYIeUEt9v-wEwPKgQ8Oe23_URsDeHCg-rR2qQK4dTxPV1J6BPTO-6Zly2H9t4sVhm0vHe8IT6sKLdX2IQ8PgGMtSHQNkpQ8zEan0CyFyUetbSW4af6mlk2pksDpvXNm5GtNTj5eTwkCQUmgGep42u5iuCGFy-o9a1cQWz45NO_J8zIYnBdOqlheNTqaMWpi4hpr-_u8Muzs4RjlEbkuYfDu7MrdsJAFwxf0BVW2cGBtB-K2jwaK7w*Auth=*873hdyjsbcvuei73hckwoxnaodbc8dnskc8HU1mKRqxh6yEU-9tqx148GqC7h90_190ZzxpEZOHAH5HTptliylRXvMPyqPyijMNu21bOA6ZhvZFuL8YNB3KF63YuV0n5TFJd1-rMI2LQIdPMVBnsxnEGrLIeFOugAFCZ_3OelAc4XjeKdDvIowxkNnvaooXT4kxtkQWzieA3JRKy3Y-Lbi7E0qiXC99GtHVDh5VWvdTs2LCv3wnRULtLp6ZCoToZ8qoUWMzU9PZldsKSnE"
m = re.search('Auth=(.+)',text).groups()[0]
print m
```

Results in:
'*873hdyjsbcvuei73hckwoxnaodbc8dnskc8HU1mKRqxh6yEU-9tqx148GqC7h90_190ZzxpEZOHAH5HTptliylRXvMPyqPyijMNu21bOA6ZhvZFuL8YNB3KF63YuV0n5TFJd1-rMI2LQIdPMVBnsxnEGrLIeFOugAFCZ_3OelAc4XjeKdDvIowxkNnvaooXT4kxtkQWzieA3JRKy3Y-Lbi7E0qiXC99GtHVDh5VWvdTs2LCv3wnRULtLp6ZCoToZ8qoUWMzU9PZldsKSnE'

Comment: Non-regex version:  `text.split("Auth=")[1]`

Comment: Copy/Paste of data block in question resulted in single line with no white space. Since the line length is ragged and no line breaks around `SID=` or `Auth=` I am assuming the data stream is not multiline. If data is in fact multiline, add the `re.MULTILINE` parameter as referenced by @Andrew. I also like the more complete expression in the example by @Leandro which names the group instead of my positional code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `re.search` instead of `re.match`, [match checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while search checks for a match anywhere in the string](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching).

You will probably also need the `re.MULTILINE` flag when creating the regex, something like this should do what you need:

```
re.search("Auth=(.*)", data, re.MULTILINE)
```

If **Auth** is not the last value then replace the `.*` with a regex that will match up until the next value.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer is correct. Also, I'd mention the named groups feature. You can easily extract parts from a regular expression:

```
import re

text = "SID=whateverAuth=myauthvalue"
m = re.search('Auth=(?P<auth>.+)', text, re.MULTILINE)
print m.group('auth') #should print myauthvalue
```

Python official docs:
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

No need for regexp, loop over the lines instead and split on `=`. A bit verbose perhaps...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("auth") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if 'Auth' in line:
            auth=line.split('=')[-1].strip()
            found=True
        if found:
            auth.join(line.strip())

*873hdyjsbcvuei73hckwoxnaodbc8dnskc8HU1mKRqxh6yEU-9tqx148GqC7h90_190ZzxpEZOHAH5HTptliylRXvMPyqPyijMNu21bOA6ZhvZFuL8YNB3KF63YuV0n5TFJd1-rMI2LQIdPMVBnsxnEGrLIeFOugAFCZ_3OelAc4XjeKdDvIowxkNnvaooXT4kxtkQWzieA3JRKy3Y-Lbi7E0qiXC99GtHVDh5VWvdTs2LCv3wnRULtLp6ZCoToZ8qoUWMzU9PZldsKSnE
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is multiline and always in the same order (SID, LSID, Auth), you can use this:

`wantedresult = originalstring.strip().split('\n')[-1].split('=')[-1]`

`strip` is necessary to remove the extra newline most servers include at the end of the original string.